# "Cable unplugged" For wireless connection

Tags: wifi

I have a USB dongle for Wifi, a TP-Link one, which is basically a realtek card (I believe). In the beginning it worked, now though Switchboard shows the oxymoron "Cable unplugged" on my wireless connection.

I've tried `sudo ifconfig wlxe8de27078274 up` and it works,  but switchboard does not change its state, even after I restart the `network-manager`. I can also successfully search for Wifi connections using `sudo iwlist wlxe8de27078274 scan | grep ESSID`, of course only after I enable the card using ifconfig. To my surprise though, `nmtui` does not show my card.

I believe the problem must be somewhere in the initialization of the card's driver when the system boots.

I've tried installing the realtek dkms drivers, and `bcmwl-kernel-source`, but to no avail.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently sometimes the wifi is getting softblocked by network manager. The solution was unblocking it using `nmcli r wifi on`. I don't really know how this happened, but it's certainly a bug. I will probably report it to the network switchboard plugin github issues later.